# Automatic string enums

Tags: typescript, enums

A string enum like the following looks quite redundant, tedious to code and prone to errors if you mistype some creating a duplicate (see as in the last one in the following sample)

```
enum Cmd{
    StartServer = "StartServer",
    StopServer = "StopServer",
    ResumServer1 = "ResumeServer1",
    ResumServer2 = "ResumeServer1"   // this would cause problems
}
```

I am looking for a way to declare only the elements of the enum and have the values automatically be the symbol name and optionally with a prefix

The farthest I arrived is to something like this:

```
export function stringifyEnum(enu:any, prefix:string=undefined){   

  Object.keys(enu).forEach( k =>{
    if (isNumber(k))
        enu[k] = prefix+enu[k]
    else
        enu[k] = prefix+k
  })
}
```

that seems to work:

```
enum Cmd{
    StartServer,
    StopServer,
    ResumeServer1,
    ResumeServer2
}

stringifyEnum(Cmd,"Cmd")
console.log(Cmd.StartServer)  // --> CmdStartServer
```

<del>With this approach, so far, the only problem is that typescript considers the enum being numerical and complains in some cases.</del>

Is there a better approach to this (the main target here is a concise enumeration) or do you see hidden risks in this idea?

Answer (score 8):

I have all but abandoned enums in TypeScript in favor of [string literal union types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html).

For your example that would look like:

```
type Cmd = 'StartServer' | 'StopServer' | 'ResumeServer1' | 'ResumeServer2';
```

This approach will give you the same benefits in compile-time checks as an enum:

```
function foo(cmd: Cmd) {}

foo('StartServer'); // OK
foo('BeginServer'); // error
```

Comment: Yes, it's something to consider. What I'd miss with this is the ability to find references to a particular element in the enum (as far as I know you can not find references to specific union elements)

Comment: and you can easily inline those enums in places where strings in general are allowed without the need of creating a variable like `const myValue: Cmd = "StopServer"; // then use myValue`. And string literals still look like magic numbers/strings.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can programmatically do a prefix so that the type system understands it; that would require some [type operations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) that are not part of the language yet.  There is an [existing suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) for this feature, but it doesn't look like anyone is working on it.

---

As for getting the key and the value to be exactly the same, you can write a function that takes a list of strings and produces a strongly-typed "enum"-like map:

```
function enumize<K extends string>(...args: K[]): {[P in K]: P} {
  const ret = {} as {[P in K]: P};
  args.forEach(k => ret[k]=k);
  return ret;
}
const Cmd = enumize("StartServer", "StopServer", "ResumeServer1", "ResumeServer2");
```

It is recognized that the value `Cmd` has the type `{ StartServer: "StartServer"; ... }`.  You will be able to access elements as expected:

```
console.log(Cmd.StartServer); // works
```

---

An official `enum` also creates some named *types*, which `enumize()` doesn't.  To fully replicate the types, you would have to more work:

```
type Cmd = keyof typeof Cmd; // allows you to refer to the type Cmd as before
```

That's the union type mentioned in @RobbyCornelissen's answer.  You need it if you're going to refer to `Cmd` as a type, as in:

```
declare function requireCmd(cmd: Cmd); // the Cmd here is a type
requireCmd(Cmd.StopServer); // works
```

If you need to refer to the types of each enum element, you have to do even more busywork, including ugly code duplication:

```
namespace Cmd {
  export type StartServer = typeof Cmd.StartServer
  export type StopServer = typeof Cmd.StopServer
  export type ResumeServer1 = typeof Cmd.ResumeServer1
  export type ResumeServer2 = typeof Cmd.ResumeServer2
}
```

That stuff would be needed to refer to types like `Cmd.StopServer` as in:

```
interface CommandInfo {
  kind: Cmd;
}

interface StopServerInfo extends CommandInfo {
   kind: Cmd.StopServer;  // need namespace for this line
   commandIssueDate: Date;
   numberOfUsersForcedOffline: number;
}
```

But if you're not going to do that very much, then you can leave out the `namespace` stuff... you can always use the type `typeof Cmd.StopServer` instead.

---

Hope that helps; good luck.

---

Comment: thank you for the detailed solution. By the way, it's a nice lesson on advanced typescript :-) I miss only the ability to search references to the enum elements  (important when refactoring and to locate use of particular elements). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to achieve the scenario where multiple keys may map to the same value, a map could get you there. You can freeze it to ensure it is immutable:

```js
const CmdMap = {
    StartServer: "StartServer",
    StopServer: "StopServer",
    ResumServer1: "ResumeServer1",
    ResumServer2: "ResumeServer1"
};

Object.freeze(CmdMap);
```

If you want to have prefixed commands, get the map from a factory:

```js
function getCommandMap(prefix: string) {
    const cmdMap = {
        StartServer: `${prefix}StartServer`,
        StopServer: `${prefix}StopServer`,
        ResumServer1: `${prefix}ResumeServer1`,
        ResumServer2: `${prefix}ResumeServer1`
    };

    Object.freeze(cmdMap);

    return cmdMap;
}

const CmdMap = getCommandMap('Cmd');

console.log(CmdMap.StartServer);
```